# I want to make the object and bind it into html in typescript

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to make the object and bind it into html file in typescript. This code is in javascript format so what should i do to make an object and bind it in html file.

```
<map>
<div>
    <div #map style="position:relative;width:100%;min-width:290px;height:600px;"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <button (click)="searchAddress()">Search</button>
</div>
</map>



showPopup(e): void {
//Get the properties and coordinates of the first shape that the event occurred on.

var p = e.shapes[0].getProperties();
var position = e.shapes[0].getCoordinates();

//Create HTML from properties of the selected result.
var html = `
  <div style="padding:5px">
    <div><b>${p.poi.name}</b></div>
    <div>${p.address.freeformAddress}</div>
    <div>${position[1]}, ${position[0]}</div>
  </div>`;

//Update the content and position of the popup.
this.popup.setPopupOptions({
    content: html,
    position: position
});.
```

Comment: Maybe, the content of the `html` variable could be a component.

Comment: @AdrienPESSU No,the content of the html variable is not a component. Its just a variable which is in javascript format. I want to convert it into typescript and make the object of this <div style="padding:5px">
    <div><b>${p.poi.name}</b></div>
    <div>${p.address.freeformAddress}</div>
    <div>${position[1]}, ${position[0]}</div>
  </div>`;          and bind it into html file

Comment: Could you please show where `showPopup()` is called from?

Comment: @MichaelD   this.map.events.add('mouseover', resultLayer, this.showPopup);